# Chart.js logarithmic line chart does not draw line on 0 values (logarithmic scale)

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js

line does not draw on line chart if all values are 0 exept one or two, it only draw the points not the whole line [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzdNA.png)

```
<canvas id="chart1" width="400" height="400" style="maxheight: 500px;"></canvas>
```

below are the options and dataset is given
this issue occurs when type on y scale is logarithmic

```
var ctx1 = document.getElementById('chart1');
var chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    "labels": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
    ],
    "datasets": [
        {
            "label": "label1",
            "data": [
                106911,
                118197,
                86819,
                105805,
                100095,
                88013,
                96532,
                81820,
                111198,
                15011
            ],
            "backgroundColor": "#EF5FA4",
            "borderColor": "#EF5FA4",
            "pointBackgroundColor": "#EF5FA4",
            "pointBorderColor": "#EF5FA4",
            "pointHoverBackgroundColor": "#fff",
            "pointHoverBorderColor": "#EF5FA4",
            "pointRadius": 1,
            "pointHoverRadius": 8,
            "pointHoverBorderWidth": 2,
            "tension": 0.3,
            "drawActiveElementsOnTop": true,
            "spanGaps": true
        },
        {
            "label": "label2",
            "data": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                1,
                0,
                0,
                0,
            ],
            "backgroundColor": "#29324E",
            "borderColor": "#29324E",
            "pointBackgroundColor": "#29324E",
            "pointBorderColor": "#29324E",
            "pointHoverBackgroundColor": "#fff",
            "pointHoverBorderColor": "#29324E",
            "pointRadius": 2,
            "pointHoverRadius": 8,
            "pointHoverBorderWidth": 2,
            "tension": 0.3,
            "drawActiveElementsOnTop": true,
            "spanGaps": true
        }
    ]
},
  options: {
    
    scales: {
      y:{
        type:'logarithmic',
        ticks:{
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          autoSkipPadding: 120,
          crossAlign: 'far',
        },
        grid:{
          display: false
        },
      },
      x:{
        grid:{
          display: false
        },
      }
    },
  }
});
```

for code information i have added this js fillde [jsFiddle]`(https://jsfiddle.net/2kd91faz/13/)`

i have attached the screenshot for what i need
[required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPB0M.png)

Comment: Where is the fiddle?

Comment: This is because log(0) is undefined, thus it will not show the line with value 0. You may refer to this GitHub issue: [Zero values skipped on logarithmic scale line chart #9629](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/9629)

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto here is the link for fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2kd91faz/13/